# Replacing only a specific value in a column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a column(`J`) in excel which has the following values:

```
11359101/2
#N/A
7349759/102
#N/A
3278023/1
```

I want to replace the "`#N/A`" with `CONCATENATE(C2,"/",0)` without changing the value of cell with `11359101/2` and others in a separate column "`I`".

Please see the screenshot for reference:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#N/A` that you want to replace is actually "Not Available" error.

Use this formula in `I1` and drag it down to apply on all the cells.

```
=IFERROR(J1, CONCATENATE($C$2,"/",0))
```

Comment: I've assumed that you want to replace all `#N/A`s with `C2`. If you don't want to keep that cell constant, remove `$`s from the formula

Comment: While I still cannot understand the OP's narrative, I suspect you are on the right track.